# Magic Mover Conversion Tool

Tags: lightning, notes, convert

I installed the [Magic Mover](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EHAmyUAH) conversion tool. We're looking to convert in sandboxes first then convert our production environment. I tested 1 record in our partial sandbox. Magic mover worked just fine.

Now I'm working on converting our full sandbox. When I click on "Convert" for both Attachments to Files and Notes Conversion, nothing's happening. Nothing in schedule jobs. Nothing is getting converted. I have read through the guide and done everything it's asking.

Any advice? I have tried both Chrome and Edge. I have also tried clearing my cache in edge.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by the Content Limits. In sandboxes, the limit is only 2500. We opened a case and had the limit increased to the maximum, which I believe is 500,000.